# How to Select only certain exact specific file names in a folder containing several files?

Tags: python

I'm using raspbery pi 3B+ w/ python.

I have a list of different files in a folder text(1).txt, picture(1).jpg, picture(2).jpg, object(1).jpg, data(1).jpg, and image(1).png.

I would like to select only files that contain the exact sequence of "picture(*any number).jpg," and ignoring the rest of the files in the folder...

Could someone help me come up with a loop that includes **`for f in os.listdir(path)`**...thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54381624/3789550

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all files in current directory with filenames that match a certain pattern in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417745/how-to-find-all-files-in-current-directory-with-filenames-that-match-a-certain-p)

Comment: What have you tried yourself, and why didn’t it work? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: What does the `*any number` part mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about to use regular expression on python.

check out this.

```
import re
name_file = 'picture(5).jpg'
p = re.compile('picture\([0-9]\)[re.S]jpg')
match = p.match(name_file )
if match:
    do_something()

name_file = 'picture(5)(6)(8).jpg'
p = re.compile('picture\([0-9]\).*[re.S]jpg')
match = p.match(name_file)
print(match)
```

[if you want more information about regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Thank you! that works well with what i'm trying to do...Also, I tried to generate a regex pattern to match only the last digit(s) within a parentheses but I can't seem to match inside the parenthesis reading from end of line to start...I have `(\d+)[^\d]*$` but that only gives any last digit, not the last digit(s) inside a parenthesis, what am I missing? For example, picture(1).jpg will match 1, picture(1)(2).jpg will match 2, but picture(1)(2)(3)-4-5-6.jpg will incorrectly match 6, even though I only want to match 3 (the last digit inside the parentheses).

Comment: you are welcome. you should read the python documentation about regular expression. but i will advice you to change the proccess's logic

Comment: `^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$` this finds a number within a parenthesis, but only the first parentheses...can you help with how to have regex read from right to left?